# Export LyX Math Equation from to Microsoft Word Math Equation

Tags: equations, lyx, msword

Is there any way to get LyX to directly convert a LyX Math Formula directly into its Microsoft Word Equation equivalent, when converting a LyX file into a Word file?  I keep getting a bad text approximation, which seems to ignore things like fractions entirely.  Its seems that with MSWord able to use LaTeX in its Equation Editor, the kind of direct conversion I mentioned should be possible.

Also, I just opened this StackExchange account, so I'm not allowed to create my own tags, or some such thing, so if someone could help me find existing tags to include for this question, that might help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! AFAIK is LyX just an editor. So your question is really how to LaTeX documents to Word. In the right column there are several posts discussing this. So you might want to have a look at these.

Comment: This is LyX-specific, as RMarkdown converts LaTeX equations accurately, but the available option to export a LyX document to a Word document just messes up the equations created using the LyX visual interface.

Comment: @MichaelChadMiller Have you read this link? https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=27764

Comment: It seems like it could be useful, but I don't know how well it converts LyX equations.  Also, I'm trying to do this on a work computer, and I'm not sure I could set this up for myself, much less for everybody.